# How to encode special characters in .vdproj registry string?

Tags: character-encoding, windows-installer, special-characters, vdproj

We got a .vdproj file that produces an .msi file. Upon installing, strings in variuous languages are added in the registry. But the special charactes comes out all wrong.

I cannot open the .vdproj as it requires VS 2005. But in text it looks like this, note the `value`:

```
"Values"
{
    "{ADCFDA98-8FDD-45E4-90BC-E3D20B029870}:_58F50CEB3EC74D5E9E6301A39929D9FE"
    {
    "Name" = "8:Description"
    "Condition" = "8:"
    "Transitive" = "11:FALSE"
    "ValueTypes" = "3:1"
    "Value" = "8:Låter dig söka efter information."
}
```

When built, this looks like the following in the generated .msi file (viewed in InstallShield):

[image]

The Swedish letters are misrepresented, and they look the same in the registry after installation:

[image]

How do I get around this? Is there a setting I could set, or an encoding I could use, directly in the vdproj value?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this for now by rephrasing without using special characters. The issue remains though, as I cannot rephrase in all languages.

The alternatives I looked at included installing Visual Studio 2005, to be able to open and edit the vbproj file, or to convert it all to WiX.

Comment: @Hans Passant, the WiX toolset allows you to set the codepage of the final MSI file which would address the issue.

Comment: @Rob - that string is encoded in code page 65001.  Can you explain what is wrong with utf-8?

Comment: The Windows Installer does not really support utf-8 in .msi files. Sad but true.